# Connecting MacBook Air to two VGA/DVI monitors

Tags: macbook-pro, display, thunderbolt

I have a 13" MacBook Air (2012) and I would like to connect it to two external Lenovo Thinkvision monitors. Both monitors are identical. They have both a VGA port and a DVI port on the back (see photo).

I am not certain how the ports can be used properly to connect the two monitors together. What is the easiest way to use them both with a MacBook Air that has only one Thunderbolt port? Can I use a Thunderbolt to VGA adapter to connect to one monitor via a VGA cable and then use a DVI cable between the two monitors?

I would like to use both monitors without purchasing an expensive piece of hardware like the [Matrox TripleHead2Go](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000RMQZ96).

[image: Back of Monitor]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

since they air only has 1 thunderbolt and some usb2 ports, you're pretty pinched.

you could get a thunderbolt dock along the lines of the caldigit unit..  this has an hdmi and a pass-through thunderbolt on it.

you can then get an hdmi-dvi cable for oen monitor and a thunderbolt to dvi adapter for the other.

another option would just be a thunderbolt hub.  neither solution is very cheap, but it willg et you wht you want.  there are also devices for usb-vga conversion, but that's a last resort, imho.

i'm curious how well these will be powered (how much resolution and how laggy) they will be, but it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Venicejeff is right.

To expand, you can't daisychain monitors that don't have a thunderbolt port on them. DVI and VGA require dedicated inputs. So if you want those two monitors you will need an adapter that gives you another video port. Like a thunderbolt dock and some adapters or that Matrox unit that you mentioned in your question.

The only other option is **one** of the Lenovo monitors and the display built into the MacBook.